# kubuntu 16.04 plasma widget on panel - icon

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma

Kubuntu 16.04. I want to run custom application/command (wine running windows app). In 14.04, I could just drag any application and edit icon settings (command + icon).

Now when I right click any icon in panel, choose "Icon settings" I can only  configure "Keyboard shortcuts". In 14.04 I had tabs "General", "Permissions", "Application" (with Command), "Preview". Where are those tabs? Why do I not see those when clicking "Icon settings" from panel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that doesn't seem to work anymore. As a work around, I first create a desktop icon (right click on the desktop -> `Create new` --> `Link to application`, and then customize it before adding to the panel.